# Organização de projetos em pacotes

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos

Estou realizando um estudo sobre Java e gostaria de aprender sem utilizar aquelas IDEs cheias de recursos que fazem tudo.
Após várias tentativas de aprender a usar pacotes, criando-os manualmente, uma classe não está conseguindo enxergar outras fora do pacote. Segue um exemplo totalmente genérico:

A estrutura de pastas é a seguinte:

```
-pacotes
 Teste.java(classe com main)
 --objeto
   Texto.java
```

E os códigos dos arquivos são os seguintes:

-> Teste.java

```
package pacotes;
import pacotes.objeto.*;

public class Teste{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Texto t = new Texto();
    }
}
```

-> Texto.java

```
package pacotes.objeto;

public class Texto{

    public Texto(){
        System.out.println("Construiu um objeto");
    }
}
```

Ao compilar o arquivo Texto.java tudo ocorre normalmente, mas ao compilar o Teste.java fala o pacote 'pacotes.objeto' não existe, o que há de errado?

Comment: Você está usando alguma IDE (Netbeans, Eclipse, etc) ou está usando apenas editor de texto (ex: bloco de notas)?

Comment: Minha intenção é evitar o netbeans ou eclipse, pois quero aprender manualmente

Comment: Foi o que pensei... pelo jeito você está tentando compilar apenas a classe Teste. Veja minha resposta abaixo mostro como compilar o projeto.

Comment: Apaguei o comentário anterior pois vi algo que não tinha na resposta aceita. Além do mais você disse que seu exemplo é completamente genérico, então o fato da classe Texto não ter um construtor público provavelmente não é um problema no seu exemplo real, entretanto vou consertar pois do jeito que está não funciona.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pelo jeito você está fazendo tudo em editor de texto, ou seja, não está usando uma IDE.

Você precisa indicar o pacote para compilar:

```
C:\Users\Leandro\Documents\Java\Exercícios\testes>javac pacotes/Teste.java
```

Comment: Obs: Veja que você precisa estar fora do diretório "pacotes" para compilar.

Comment: Muito legal, você me salvou, tipo, agora eu não posso fazer um   ...teste/pacotes/java Teste

Comment: agora, quando eu for rodar um projeto feito e pacotes, tenho que compilar todas as minhas classes sem main pelo metodo normal, e depois compilar a principal deste jeito

Comment: Você pode compilar seu pacote base: Ex: c:\javac pacotes/*.java

Comment: informações realmente úteis

Comment: Ainda assim é sempre melhor usar uma IDE para não ter que se preocupar com isso.

Answer (score 2):

Não use wildcards isto é *****

com isso poderá fazer:

```
package pacotes;

import pacotes.objeto.Texto;


public class Teste{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Texto t = new Texto();
    }
}
```

Detalhe o construtor de Texto deve ser declarado como público (se não fica como protected e restrito ao pacote `pacotes.objeto`).

```
package pacotes.objeto;

public class Texto{

    public Texto(){
        System.out.println("Construiu um objeto");
    }
}
```

Comment: Droga, agora lendo sua resposta acho que não deveria ter editado a pergunta, mas assim, o problema de não achar a classe era um problema com o classpath, não com a visibilidade do construtor. Para acrescentar, o fato de usar wildcard ou não, não vai interferir no resultado. A resposta é usar corretamente o classpath. Sobre a minha edição na pergunta, se quiser eu posso reverter (ou você mesmo pode).

Comment: @Math acho que não tenho reputação necessária para reverter sua edição. Quanto a wildcards, não era o erro que ele estava encontrando mais ainda assim [não são recomendados](http://javadude.com/articles/importondemandisevil.html)